# ActionMailer rails, how to send diffrent content to cc: @email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I send an email after the user creates a record, I'm sending some data of the record `to:` @email and I need to send to cc: `cc@email` all the record information. How can I do that?

```
  def appointment_confirmation(appointment)
    @appointment = appointment
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: appointment.email, subject: "Appointment Confirmation", cc: "cc@email"
  end
```

Comment: I guess it's not possible, so the only solution would be to send 2 different mails

Comment: I think you're missing the point of "carbon copy".

Comment: You would need to trigger another Emailer Action, passing some params about the email you just sent, and prepare the new email to cc@email.com

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to send a separate email using a separate template.

CC means "Carbon Copy" and can only be the exact same email.